# Will Posting a Link to My Site in Every Tweet Have a Negative Impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, facebook, twitter, negative-seo

I have a site that auto-posts to twitter (and facebook) different content from my site (always unique) about 5 times per day.  Will including a backlink to my site in every post negatively (or positively) impact the SEO of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't hurt SEO to tweet links from your site.   [This site has a twitter bot](https://twitter.com/stackwebmasters) that does so.   The NY times tweets all its stories.

Google usually does monitor the twitter stream.  It uses that data to discover content.  Tweeting a link from your site to a new article has been a good way to alert Googlebot to the link before scrapers can steal it.  I haven't seen evidence that Google uses twitter links to pass PageRank.  Twitter links probably don't help rankings in any way.